# Why are my user accounts missing from login screen after upgrade to 14.04 from 12.04 ?

Tags: upgrade, login, users, 14.04

Upgraded my 12.04LTS to 14.04 LTS via DVD, choosing the "upgrade" option from the installation options prompt.

Since then, in the Login screen, the older user accounts are not visible. They are however visible if I navigate to the home screen. Those are protected and even as admin

Below is the output of  `grep /bin/bash /etc/passwd`  :

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
admin1:x:1000:1000:admin,,,:/home/admin1:/bin/bash
dranand:x:1001:1001:Anand Philip,,,:/home/dranand:/bin/bash
```

Here is the output of  `ls -l /home`. (The new profiles I have created during the upgrade are marked.)

```
drwx------ 18 admin1  admin1  4096 Apr 21 17:35 admin1 [NEW]
drwxr-xr-x 21    1004    1004 4096 Apr 11 12:48 dmishariff [OLD]
drwxr-xr-x  2 dranand dranand 4096 Apr 21 16:58 dranand [NEW]
drwxr-xr-x 36    1002    1002 4096 Apr 21 16:15 dranandphilip [OLD]
drwxr-xr-x 28 admin1  admin1  4096 Apr 15 16:07 nationwide [OLD]
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I was upgrading from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 and it crashed mid way through the process. I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu from a USB drive and chose the option to keep my files and users but ran into the same issue that you're having.

The following worked for me:

1. Create a new user with the same exact username as the one lost.
2. Open Terminal
3. `id -u username`
4. My uid was `1001` shown in example below, replace this with your uid.
5. `sudo useradd --home /home/username --uid 1001 --gid users username`
6. `sudo chown -R username: ~username`

See here for more explanation:
http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/681

Comment: Thanks! Turns out, that just creating a user with the exact name was enough. Strangely enough,it did not let me do this during the installation, when I tried making users with same IDs as before.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem in ubuntu 20.04. It was due to the shell change after removing zsh. What I did:

1. Go to /var/lib/AccountsService/user and update SystemAccount to 'false'.
2. Check /etc/passwd and verify correct shell is mentioned at the end of the username. (here is is /bin/bash)
   eg: <>:x:1001:1001:Viraj Perera,,,:/home/<>:/bin/bash