# Lost user login on upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, login, users

I just upgraded to 13.10 this weekend (I know 14.04 is out, I'm not doing that yet) and have lost my login. There used to be two user accounts I could choose to log in from on the startup page, mine and the dummy one created by a coworker when he was helping me with something. After the upgrade, the only user account I could log in to belongs to my coworker. My account data is still there (I can access it  when I log in as him and cd to /home/username) but I don't know how to log in as my old user account. It also doesn't show up in the user accounts Settings view. How do I add it back?

Note: I tried using the answer to this question: [Why are my user accounts missing from login screen after upgrade to 14.04 from 12.04 ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452048/why-are-my-user-accounts-missing-from-login-screen-after-upgrade-to-14-04-from-1?rq=1) and got the response "user 'username' already exists"

Comment: `sudo userdel username` and then `useradd`?

Comment: won't that delete the account and related files? I just want a way to be able to log in.

Comment: It shouldn't unless you add `--remove` flag. See `userdel --help`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` as root and add:

```
greeter-hide-users=false
greeter-show-manual-login=true
allow-guest=false
```

When I go to the startup screen, I am now able to type in my username and log in.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install lightdm again enter from the terminal:

```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

it should work fine that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem you could also try to enter in the terminal:

```
    sudo apt-get autoremove gdm
    sudo apt-get autoremove lightdm
```

and then in the terminal enter:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install lightdm
    sudo apt-get install gdm
```

and then in the terminal enter:

```
    sudo -f --dismiss-Option::="unity-greeter-gtk" install --reinstall unity-greeter
```

and then reconfigure the unity-greeter enter in the terminal:

```
    sudo apt-get --reconfigure unity-greeter
```

and this could maybe also work fine this way.